# Java JFileChooser to select bitmap image

Tags: java, oop, image-processing, bitmap, jfilechooser

Basically, all that I am trying to do is use the JFileChooser to open a bitmap image from the user's computer, and then edit the indivudal pixels with a simple filter. I would like to get to the point of being able to save the image the same way that you open it, but before I do that, I need to figure out how to actually open a file with JFileChooser. My problem is that I set inputFile equal to what the input.getSelectedFIle() is, which would work, but it is in an if statement. That being said, how would I fix this, and have the file be used outside of the if statement? Also, is there a particular way that I would need to save the bitmap image after the filter is applied?

Here is my code; it may contain a few errors due to me testing stuff to try to fix the problem:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class JavaImage
{
private static Component parent;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    FileInputStream in;
    //try catch around the image selection
    try
    {
        JFileChooser input = new JFileChooser();
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                "BMP Images", "bmp");
        input.setFileFilter(filter);
        int returnVal = input.showOpenDialog(parent);
        File inputFile = input.getSelectedFile();
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            inputFile = input.getSelectedFile();
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(inputFile);
        }
        new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("output.bmp");

        //user selected bitmap image file
        in=FileInputStream(inputFile);


    int i = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    //edits the actual pixels of the bitmap image
    while((i==in.read())&&i!=-1) {
        if (++counter>54)   // skip past Bitmap headers
        {
            //use BGR format subpixels to process 
            int b =i; //stores blue byte
            int g = in.read(); //read green bye
            int r = in.read();//read red byte

            //greyscale
            int gray = (r+g+b)/3;
            b=gray; g=gray; b=gray;



            out.write(b);// output the blue byte
            out.write(g);// output the green byte
            i=r; //prep red byte for output

        }
        out.write(i);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();

}
//the error message if user enters a non bitmap file
    catch (IOException ImageError)
        {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "No such file");
        }
}
}
```

Comment: For one, change `in=FileInputStream(inputFile);` to `in = new FileInputStream(inputFile);`

Comment: Next of all, please clarify this statement: `"My problem is that I set inputFile equal to what the input.getSelectedFIle() is, which would work, but it is in an if statement."`. What do you mean by this? Why not put all in the if block? And why use a Scanner for a bitmap file, a file that is obviously not text.

Comment: Also, call `input.getSelectedFile()` only if `returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION`, not before testing this. Else you're in for trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I changed the line with the FileInputStream and set the inputFile to null instead of calling input.getSelectedFile().

Comment: On the second question, could I actually have the if statement run throughout the entire program, rather than ending it? Also, what do you suggest that I use instead of Scanner? (Or do I even need that line?)

Comment: Scanner is for text files only. Are you dealing with a text file here?? It sure doesn't sound like it. You're reading in data. If you're reading in an image myself, I'd use `ImageIO.read(...)` to read it into a BufferedImage. You can extract the data from the BufferedImage's raster (I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You kind of on the right track, but unless the user selects the `JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION`, you should do nothing (as the dialog was closed by the use cancelling it)

```
JFileChooser input = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
            "BMP Images", "bmp");
input.setFileFilter(filter);
if (input.showOpenDialog(parent) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File inputFile = input.getSelectedFile();
    // Process file
}
```

You can more easily load an image using `ImageIO` which will allow you access to the underlying pixel data.  See [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details.

If you're still hell bent on processing the file manually, then you really should also take a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and manage your resources better